# C# Visual Studio Debug DoDragDrop causes Win32 Exception clipboard format registration did not suceed

Tags: c#, winforms, tuples

So I've been trying to pass Tuple data types in the DoDragDrop method of a winforms control. This does not appear to possible. I do get a Win32 Exception saying that clipboard was unable to register the format. It works fine with other datatypes which are not Tuple.

Is there any way to pass a tuple in a DataObject?

This applies to both normal Tuples and Value Tuples.

This does not happen with every Tuple .... Currently the following has been observed:

```
Tuple<RefType, RefType> does not work
Tuple<RefType, baseType> does work
Tuple<RefType> does work
Tuple<object, object> does work
```

This appears to be somewhat specific to my project as I am currently unable to make a minimal example that shows the same behaviour ...

Apparently its specific to the solution. I did make a minimal test project in the solution the error appears in and made it an independent project that starts up by itself. The error happens. If I reference that project in a different solution and run it, the error does not happen.

The error also only happens in Debug mode. If I run the application outside of Visual Studio it does not happen.

Comment: Just a thought: C# tuples are value types but a DataObject probably needs to be a reference type. Have you tried using the original Tuple types?  The `ToTuple` and `ToValueTuple` extension methods should help with translation both ways.

Comment: I was using normal Tuples before. That didn't work. I just checked with Value Tuples that also doesn't work.

Comment: Are the problem types marked Serializable?

Comment: They are not. However using the exact same types in a different application works.... Also even using an empty class fails. I'm a bit stumped for ideas right now

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this had nothing to do with DoDragDrop or Tuples in the end.

Deleting the .vs folder inside the solution made the error go away. Apparently something was misconfigured/broken inside there. No clue what however.

You might try this if you run into a similar problem